# Lua and 3 requirement "if" statements

Tags: lua, operands

I'm fiddling with some code I found on some forums, but I've only ever learned Java, so I'm a little out of my element. Here's the snippet I'm playing with:

```
/run 
function FnH() 
  for i=0,4 do 
    for j=1,GetContainerNumSlots(i) do 
      local t={GetItemInfo(GetContainerItemLink(i,j) or 0)}
      if t[7]=="Herb" and select(2,GetContainerItemInfo(i,j))>=5 then 
        return i.." "..j, t[1]
      end 
    end 
  end
end
```

This is using WoW's addon API. With what little I know, this is a search and make a list function that lists items that let t[7]=Herb while also having more than 5 of them. If Lua does arrays similarly, t[0] should be Item Name. I want to exclude an item with the name "blahblah", but I don't understand Lua's boolean operands.

In Java, it would be something along the lines of

```
if(itemX.getItemType()=="Herb" && itemX.getAmount()>5 && itemX.getName()!="blahblah")
do stuff
else skip to next item
```

I see with Lua that they use "and" and "or", but how do I say "and not this"?

Comment: Negation is `not`. Inequality is `~=`.

Comment: How would I use those? Would "not" be used in the same place as the "and" in this situation to negate parameters? 

With inequality, I'm assuming it returns true so long as the two compared numbers are different?

Comment: `and`, `or`, and `not` are equivalent to `&&`, `||`, and `!` respectively in C-like languages such as Java; you use them in almost the exact same way.

Answer (score 2):

> If Lua does arrays similarly, t[0] should be Item Name.

Note that Lua indexes tables starting from index 1, not 0 like some other languages, so if you have table `local t = {"John", "Laura", "Herb"}`, then `t[1] == "John"` and `t[3] == "Herb"`.

As others have said, the equivalent Lua operations are `and`, `or`, and `not`, with inequality written as `~=`, so the code you have can be written as:

```
if itemX.getItemType() == "Herb"
and itemX.getAmount() > 5
and itemX.getName() ~= "blahblah" then
  -- do stuff
else
  -- skip to next item
end
```

You can also change the last condition to `and not (itemX.getName()=="blahblah")` as these are equivalent.

Also, I'm not sure about WoW API, but those `itemX` calls should probably be `itemX:getItemType()`, `itemX:getAmount()` and so on (note using `:` notation instead of `.` notation); see [OO-programming section](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) in Programming in Lua.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to translate your java code straight to Lua, and you can see if it makes sense to you

```
    if itemX.getItemType() == "Herb" and itemX.getItemAmount() > 5 and itemX.getItemName ~= "blahblah" then do
        --do stuff here
    end
    else
        --skip to the next item
    end
```

Comment: No need for `do ... end`.

Comment: For me its a habit, but yes, it is not required